# rSplit file names according to some rules?

Tags: python-3.x, string, split

I have 1.5M files with 2 patterns:

```
"userId_page.jpg"
"date_userId_page.jpg"
```

I want to be able to split the file name to 2 or 3 parts according to the given patterns.
I know I can use:

```
file_name = '/2020_03_10_123456_001.jpg'
date_part, user_id, page_num = file_name.rsplit('_', 2)
```

and if my filename consists only from ID and page:

```
file_name = '/12232454345234_005.jpg'
user_id, page_num = file_name.rsplit('_', 1)
```

Should I count the number of `"_"` in each case and `rsplit` it with 1 or 2?
Is there any other better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to match the different parts and then assign them to each of the variables. By using an optional group, we can get one regex to match both filename patterns; when there is no `date_part` that variable will be an empty string:

```
import re

file_name = '/2020_03_10_123456_001.jpg'
date_part, user_id, page_num = re.findall(r'(?:(\w+)_)?(\d+)_(\d+)\..*$', file_name)[0]
print(f'date={date_part}, user={user_id}, page={page_num}')
file_name = '/12232454345234_005.jpg'
date_part, user_id, page_num = re.findall(r'(?:(\w+)_)?(\d+)_(\d+)\..*$', file_name)[0]
print(f'date={date_part}, user={user_id}, page={page_num}')
```

Output:

```
date=2020_03_10, user=123456, page=001
date=, user=12232454345234, page=005
```